# How to display images dynamically in React based on the respose from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling the **OpenWeatherMap** API and getting in the response the icon id like **'01d'** or **'04n'**.
I've set up all the images under a local directory in /src and named them **'01d.png'**, **'04n.png'** etc.

I've passed this icon id via props to my **Current.js** component and I don't know how can I display the image with the specific id name.

e.g: `props.icon == '01d'` => display image 01d.png

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Current.module.css';

const current = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Current}>
            <p>Temperature: {props.temperature}</p>
            <p>Minimum Temperature: {props.minimumTemperature}</p>
            <p>Maximum Temperature: {props.maximumTemperature}</p>
            <p>Humidity: {props.humidity}</p>
            <img src={'../../icons/' + props.icon} alt={props.icon}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default current;
```

Comment: You're missing ```.png```

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't the case. I've actually forgot to add the + '.png' when I copied the code from VS Code. Thanks for the suggestion anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Current.module.css';

const current = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.Current}>
            <p>Temperature: {props.temperature}</p>
            <p>Minimum Temperature: {props.minimumTemperature}</p>
            <p>Maximum Temperature: {props.maximumTemperature}</p>
            <p>Humidity: {props.humidity}</p>
            <img src={`../../icons/'${props.icon}.png`} alt={props.icon}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default current;
```

Instead of using + operator to concatenate strings, you can use the handy template literal to make it a lot easier for you to concatenate strings together. Also add the .png format to the end of your file path since its an image you specify the extension name

Comment: I've tried as you suggested and even deleted the apostrophe inside the backticks and the results were the same. Maybe I need to import them somewhere? Because when I do 'import icon from blablabla' and use it like src={icon} it displays correctly. Any suggestions?